# Can't access objects within array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

So I am running a few $http.get requests within a forloop and storing the results within an array. When I run:
`console.log(episodesObj[0])` it returns `undefined`. However when I run `console.log(episodesObj)` it returns the whole array:

[image]

Below is the code I am running

````
    var episodesObj = [];
    for(i=1;i<=num_seasons;i++) {
      $http.get('/api/show/<%=show.id%>/season/'+i)
      .then(response => {
        episodesObj.push(response.data)
      });
    }
    console.log(episodesObj); ```
````

Comment: Can you paste your array as code instead of screenshot?

Comment: My best guess is lazy console and a dupe of "how to return the result of an asynchronous call", but as you show zero code, it's kinda impossible to answer

Comment: @mickl https://pastebin.com/1pN28j82 - Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Show us the code that is leading up to the console.log (and including)

Comment: @Sturm  I have edited the question to include the code.

Comment: The callback provided to `$http.get().then` is not guaranteed to have finished before your console.log statement.

Comment: Well, i guess i was right. Glass-ball wins this time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Also related, as mentioned above: [is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) - you can clearly see in your screenshot, that the initial array it displays is empty. You just clicked and expanded it after the results were already in, and the lazy evaluation then displayed those.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the final result, you could use [promise all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

> **all(promises);**
>
> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of > the input promises are resolved.

Something like:

```
var listOfPromises = [];
for(i=1;i<=num_seasons;i++) {      
    listOfPromises.push($http.get('/api/show/<%=show.id%>/season/'+i))     
}


$q.all(listOfPromises).then(function(result){
   
    // we run this code once all promises are resolved
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        episodesObj.push(result[i]);
    }
   
   console.log(episodesObj);
});
```

Comment: @downvoter, what wrong with my answer? write a comment

Comment: However, as mentioned, not my downvote, so i cannot retract either. Whoever downvoted, probably isn't even watching anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're not pushing the response to your array until after the http call completes, so if you immediately log `episodesObj[0]`, of course it's undefined.

Chrome keeps live references to non-primitive things you console log, so when the http calls eventually update the array, it's also updated in the console, which is why you're able to view it later.